# .mp4 not playing with html5 tag video on chrome

Tags: html5-video

The code is:

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

but it didn't play on chrome ,and I've tried the code under:

```
if (window.chrome) {
    $("[type=video\\\/mp4]").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(".mp4", "_c.mp4"));
    });
}
```

but it didn't work either. Does anyone has the same problem? Any solution?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: Check if you have any errors in the Console or Network tab of the chrome developer tools.